# PhpStorm: How to configure the purple box around statements in sql files?

Tags: mysql, ide, phpstorm, syntax-highlighting

Since a few days, PhpStorm is showing a purple box around my SQL statements in sql files. I don't dislike the feature, I just really don't know why this is suddenly there - and on my collegues PhpStorm it is not. How can I configure that?

[image]

Thanks for clarification.

Comment: 1) Your IDE version exactly (`Help | About`) 2) Is this unmodified Default color schema, I assume? If not -- please show screenshots using either Default or Darcula 3) Any 3rd party & not bundled by default plugin? Especially those that work with SQL/DB? 4) Please share the actual file (could contain any SQL code as long as it provides such behaviour) and describe what you are doing (where do you see it etc). Ideally it would be great if you can create a sample project, zip and share it completely as it may contain some extra config that I may be missing.

Comment: (1) PhpStorm 2016.1.1 - Build #PS-145.970, built on May 3, 2016
(2) Unmodified Default color schema
(3) The custom plugins I have:
- .ignore
- CMD Support
- PHP Annotations
- String Manipulation
(4) Now that you point it out, it's interesting: I only get this in one file - not in the other sql files. So it seems to be some configuration of the file. Doesn't matter what is written in the file - just every sql command will get a box around.

Comment: No real ideas so far ... 1) Maybe post whole file screenshot (so that I can see what name & icon it has  etc) 2) Can you record a short video (screencast) that will demonstrate the behaviour? 3) Try changing editor color schema to Darcula -- do you see anything similar? And now back to Default -- is it still there?